# Race condition on go

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

When the code is ran time taken by attack() function is printed sometimes
I know their is race condition when attack writes to channel and main reads it then main exits and doesn't wait for timer("attack") to execute

I am new to go:_)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)


func timer(funcName string) func(){
    startTime := time.Now()
    return func(){
        fmt.Printf("%s took %v time to run \n", funcName, time.Since(startTime))
    }
}

func main(){
    defer timer("main")()
    smokeSignal := make(chan bool)
    evilNinga := "Tommy"
    go attack(evilNinga, smokeSignal)
    fmt.Println(<-smokeSignal)
}

func attack(target string, smokeSignal chan<-bool){
    defer timer("attack")()
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Throwing ninja stars at ", target)
    smokeSignal <- true
}
```

Can some tell how to handle this case, I want to print time taken by both the function, and use channels

Comment: You can send the smokesignal inside the defer of attack and not at the end) to ensure goroutine is ``terminated'' before main. `defer func() { timer("attack")(); smokeSignal <- true }()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can some tell how to handle this case

When `main` exits, the program is terminated, there is no graceful termination of concurrent goroutines (in many programs the non-main goroutines are ancillary "daemons" and not expected to shut down at all) so no guarantee extant defers will run. This is what occurs here: when you send the smoke signal, if the `attack` goroutine is descheduled then main can return before it gets re-scheduled, and thus `defer` never runs.

There are a number of options to handle this issue, but all of them lead to basically the same thing: ensure you send on the channel *after* the function has run, which you can do by for instance (non-exhaustive)

- defer sending the message before the timer (defers run in reverse order)
- defer() in a sub-function, signal in the outer function
- don't use defer, just run the exit message before sending the signal
- instead of separately messaging and printing, send the function's run time over the channel, and have the caller format and report that